# Trivial front page URL in PHP question

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to show an image link (image is on my server) in the PHP block (Drupal 7). When I put

```
<?php
print '<p align="right"><a href="http://something.com"> <img src="'.$front_page.'/misc/something.png">Caption</a>';
?>
```

it works but picture is only visible on the front page, on others it shows broken link. Why?
What should I add then to this concatenation to make it work and to avoid putting hardcoded page URL?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of $front_page?

Comment: Hmmm, like `print $front_page`? There's nothing

Comment: Is it empty in both cases (front page and other pages with the broken path)?

Comment: Yes, empty in both cases (front and nodes). Or maybe I'm displaying it wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal, you should be able to run it through `url()` to get a proper path, i.e. `url('misc/something.png')`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to troubleshoot this issue is to look at the src attribute of the page when the image is visible, and compare it to the src attribute of the page when the image is not visible. The differences may be revealing.

If this does not solve the problem, check to see if one of your pages uses a `<base>` tag. This may be adding data to your image path in an unexpected manner.

Comment: Ok, now I see the difeerence - it adds 'node' after front page URL, but how can I fix this ?

Comment: The easy, non-coding way is to create a directory alias from 'node' to your image directory. Then all requests (regardless of the path) will end up in the same place. The alternative is to dive into the code to determine what is adding the 'node' string.

Answer (score 0):

@Gawi, When possible, you should really use Drupal's API to add links, images, etc instead of hard-coding them.  For example:

```
<?php
  GLOBAL $base_url;
  $variables = array('path' => $base_url . '/misc/blog.png', 'alt' => 'something.com logo');

  print '<p align="right">' . l(theme('image', $variables) . 'Caption', $base_url, array('html' => TRUE)). '</p>';
?>
```

Documentation on the variables/functions used:

- [$base_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--globals.php/global/base_url/7)
- [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l)
- [theme_image()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_image/7)